# How to update a column within a query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to update a column using aggregate function but I don't want to loop through each row.
I'm coming from SQL Server where we do something like

```
With CTE as (select name, price, cost,  quantity price*quantity as total)
update CTE 
   set cost = total
```

With this I am able to update whole table without looping through every record. How can I accomplish the same task in mysql

Comment: `total` is derived, there's no real advantage in storing it permanently on the table since it's just a simple multiplication. There's real disadvantages in storing it  permanently on the table since it can lead to your data being inconsistent if you fail to keep the column values up to date.

Comment: On the contrary is has the opposite effect. The costs are calculated once from another table which keeps changing. So if you need to view costs of items purchased earlier after the price has changed, you'd see a wrong value if you calculated the cost dynamically. It was a tough decision though. You know sometimes requirements force bad designs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do computation :

```
update sales 
    set cost = price * quantity
where . . . ;
```

However, the same would be work with `SQL Server` no need to use updateble `CTE` :

Comment: @KMarto . . . And you would use the same syntax in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to not store `cost` column at all. Instead create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW sales_with_cost 
AS 
select name, price, cost,  quantity, price*quantity as total FROM sales
```

You can use `sales_with_cost` instead of `sales` directly and can ensure that your data is consistent without needing to do an update.